# Just some fun user stats

Tags: discussion, users, statistics

We know which users are the most reputed [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)

We know which users vote the most [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all)

We know there are 12k+ users [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism)

But..

Reputation is based on question/answer score, but does not include comments, and doesn't factor efficiency.
Voting includes both UP & DOWN votes.
Many users are not active.

On slightly deeper analysis...

**Top 25 chatterz** (comments):

[image]

**Top 20 loverz** (upvote/downvote ratio):

[image]

**Top 15 haterz** (downvote/upvote ratio):

[image]

**Top 10 strikerz** (reputation per post):

[image]

**Top 5 clapperz** (upvote but never post):

[image]

**Spectatorz** (never participated):

[image]

P.S: some artistic license was taken to filter for at least X votes, or Y reputation etc.

Comment: Mr.Alien's love is infinite. You can't even measure it!

Comment: What is comments score and how did you calculate that data? Is it present in our profiles?

Comment: @Rickross, sum of scores of all comments

Comment: Damn it! I couldn't made it even in a single list. Disappointing :-/

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto same here):

Comment: 5 - 6 months earlier I used to wonder what might be that one post which Sai has downvoted... Seeing above today I'm again reminded of it...

Comment: This is fun. How about a post on meta site?

Comment: My ratio was 6 but now I have improved it to 8.1 .. @ram

Comment: My ratio is now greater than 11 @mar

Answer (score 2):

> Voting includes both UP & DOWN votes.
>
> On slightly deeper analysis...
>
> Top 15 haterz (downvote/upvote ratio):
>
> Top 20 loverz (upvote/downvote ratio):

I don't understand the point of publicly posting analysis of voting patterns of users 
along with their names.

FYI, [a previous post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/541/voting-tendency-and-data-in-hinduism-se) that did similar "research" was deleted by a mod.

Comment: the data is already public

Comment: I don't know why the same action didn't happen this time. The moderators did not change.